# Connection between angle and arc length

Tags: angle, arc-length

I read somewhere that the angle corresponds arc length in the unit circle. In other word if we have a circle with center placed on the origin and have radius equal to $1$ then length of the circular arc from point $(\cos t, \sin t)$ to point$(1,0)$ is correspond to angle. It doesn't make sense to me.

For example It is obvious to me if we represent an angle with degree, for instance $60^\circ$ the angle correspond to ratio of it to $360^\circ$ or it is $\frac 16$ of the whole circle. I know it is not precise statement but at least It make sense to me. But in the case above,
I can't make a connection between **arc length of the unit circle** and **angle**, because on the one hand we have the **length** but on the other hand we have **angle**.

Comment: [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

Comment: I think, if my memory is right, that **angle (in radian) = (arc length)/(radius)**

Comment: See [Arc lenght: circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Arcs_of_circles): If $\theta$  is in *radians* then $s =r \theta$. This is a definition of the radian. When $r=1$, then $s=\theta$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, am I correct ?

Comment: @Spectre - YES.

Comment: Thanks... and so an explanation for his doubt is : since the radius of the unit circle is gonna be $1$ unit, the arc length would correspond to the angle, right ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think the key is:  "The length of an arc of a unit circle is numerically equal to the measurement in radians of the angle that it subtends". but I don't understand it.

Comment: @soheil , the thing is that the circumference of a unit circle is going to be $2\pi$, so for whatever angle in degrees you choose, the angle would be equal to a part of the circumference.

Comment: And thus, you get the angle in radian if you use the relation $\theta = \frac{l}{r}$ ($l$ = arc length, $r$ = radius).

Comment: The radian is a number (**no** unit of measure) ranging from $0$ to $2 \pi$. The formula for the circumference of the circle is $c=2 \pi r$, where $r$ is the *radius*. In the unit circle we have $r=1$. Thus, if we choose as reference meters, we have $r=1$ meter. Thus circumf $c= 2 \pi 1= 2 \pi$ meters.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, just the same as what I said ☺

Answer (score 1):

The radius of a unit circle is $1$ m, and hence the circumference of the circle is $2\pi\times 1$m $= 2\pi$ m. Thus, for whatever angle in degrees the arc subtends to the centre, the arc length is a part of the circumference (yeah, we all know it) and using the formula for finding the angle subtended by an arc (i.e. , $\theta = \frac{l}{r}$, $l$ = arc length, $r$ = radius), you get that $\theta = l$ in radian (rather than in degrees, but the result you get is equal to the angle in degrees times $\frac{\pi}{180}$ ).

If you were not looking for an answer like this, refer @JoshuaWang's or @QED's answers.

Comment: So the key here is the formula $\theta=\frac{l}{r}$ . How we can obtain this?

Comment: @soheil I think that this was made in the same way as trigonometric ratios were made.

Comment: But in this case, I think the makers took an infinestimal arc to determine the ratio between the arc's length and the radius

Comment: Then they must have used the small angle approximation and all that  (which I am not pretty aware of).

Comment: You may refer here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian - Just the same thing that @MauroALLEGRANZA posted, I think.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I should read this, because I have some problem with basic definitions.

Comment: @soheil , you took the right decision. You are welcome

Comment: @soheil, another thing I can say is that : if you move a line segment of infinestimal length around the centre through a particular angle $theta$, you get an arc of length $l$. So basically, the relation should have come from that thought : $l = \theta \times r$. I am not sure, but this is what I feel.

Comment: Or you can say, the formula shows the length of the same arc on the unit circle corresponding to the arc on the circle at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. To make the connection, we have to make the radius of the circle constant. Then, angle is defined as $\frac{\text{arc length}}{\text{radius}}$. Interestingly, both have dimensions of length, making the measure of angle unitless.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **arcs of equal length subtends equal angle at the center of a circle**. Thus a function, $f:[0,2\pi]\to[0,2\pi]$, mapping a real number $\ell$ to the angle subtended at the center of the unit circle by an arc of length $\ell$, is well defined.

> Can you show that this function satisifies $f(c\ell)=cf(\ell)$ for any $c\in\Bbb{R},\ell\in[0,2\pi]$ such that $c\ell\in[0,2\pi]$?

Then you know that the circumference of the circle is $2\pi$, and the considering the circle as an arc, the angle subtended by the circle at the center is $2\pi$. Hence $f(2\pi)=2\pi$. So you can deduce that $f(\theta)=\theta$ for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.